# Running while loop to create linked lists in java

Tags: java, linked-list

So I have a while loop that captures each line of strings from an external file and separates them word by word using string tokenizer. Next, each word is to go into a linked list that is connected. Since each line is different size, I don't know how I would program it so the linked list is created as many times as needed.

For example:

first line in file = "Hi how are you"
second line in file = "I am good how are you"

As you can see the second line will have more words with the string tokenizer than the first one. How would I go about solving such a problem?

**I am a student and still learning and I must use linked lists...no arrays.**

I truly appreciate your help.

---

here is the code for main block:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
      dataInpt=new File("C:\\sentences.txt");
      inFile=new Scanner(dataInpt);
      StringTokenizer myTokens;
      String line, sentence;
      Node node1 = new Node();
      while (inFile.hasNextLine())
      {
        line=inFile.nextLine();
        myTokens=new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (myTokens.hasMoreTokens())
        {
          sentence=myTokens.nextToken();
```

as you can see that is not complete. I don't know what would I do next because if I do node.value=myTokens.nextToken(); , then it would only save that word onto the node instead of adding a node for each word while linking all the nodes so node="Hi" and node.next="How" and node.next.next="are"...etc.

here is the class for Node:

```
public class Node
{
  public Object value;
  public Node next;

  public Node()
  {
    value=null;
    next=null;
  }
  public Node (Object value, Object value2, Node next)
  {
    this.value=value;
    this.next=next;
  }
}
```

If you have any more questions, please ask. I really need help on this.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you want to insert in the list? What is your actual problem?

Comment: _"I must use linked lists...nothing else."_ - What about variables, flow control structures, ...?

Comment: Here's a tip for you - linked lists can contain other linked lists.

Comment: As the string tokenizer separates the sentence into individual words like "Hi" "How"...etc., I want to insert those words in a linked list at the same time. The problem and the question, is how would I program it so the linked list is only created and new values are only added if there is another word?

Comment: Since you're essentially rolling your own linked list class and not using Java's predefined one, you should really study your text for I'm sure it covers the algorithm to manage one. Here's a [link](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/collections/lists/simple-linked-list.html) that might help you. I'd recommend keeping track of the "head" and possibly the "tail" nodes of your line's list, and for each word simply create a new node, assign the "tail's" next pointer to it, and the tail node to this new node's previous pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
List list = new LinkedList<String>();

while (something) {
    /* tokenise words here */

    list.add(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String line = "Hi how are you";

LinkedList<String> wordsAsList = new LinkedList<String>(
   Arrays.asList(line.split("\\s+"))
)
```

Comment: This actually does use arrays, since the `split` method on a `String` returns an array.

Comment: That hadn't been ruled out when I answered it

Answer (score 0):

So, you've implemented your own linked list using nodes. You have the right idea so far: for each line, you separate each word in the line and do something with it. Because you need to implement the *pointers* that connect each Node, here is the main thing you might consider doing: Figure out a way to save the *previous* word so that you can create the proper links between Nodes. This might mean needing to store a pointer outside your innermost `while()` loop.

Comment: I have edited the question with the code... you can see it and you will understand better what my question is.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'with code'. You only mentioned you can't use arrays...?

Comment: I just added the code and I told you that before I added it. I am sorry about that...now you can see the code

Comment: @user Because this is homework, I'm not going to write the code for you. Instead, most people here will just give you hints.

Comment: I asked a question almost a month ago and people did give me hints at first so I understand. You can see the code so it would be great of you to help me with some hint or any form of help.

Comment: I apologize, I have a bit of homework of my own. If you don't get any good answers soon, I'll spend some time giving you whatever hints I can.

Comment: ok, well I will wait for 10 more minutes and then reply back here, please do check

Comment: I am sorry it doesn't help...Please see me in chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7709/discussion-between-user1079641-and-simchona)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: you don't have to know how many elements will be in your list.

The longer answer: One of the main benefits to a linked list is that it grows dynamically.  If you have N nodes in your list, and you add a new node to the head of the list, the existing nodes don't need to change.  You don't need to initialize a new array, or copy elements, or anything except the node you are currently adding to the list.

So, for your specific problem, you probably want to create a new linked list for each line of the file, and then add each word of the line to the linked list.  When you are done reading the line, you will have a linked list full of the words for that line, and then you can print or otherwise use that list.

Answer (score 0):

As someone hinted at, it sounds as though you wish to make a link list with each of its node relating to one line of the file. Each line, however, is then represented as it's own linked list of words. In other words, you're looking to make a linked list of linked list. I'm not sure what the restrictions are for this assignment of yours, but it sounds like you are required to roll your own "Node" class. I'd recommend rolling your own "LinkedList" class, too... but that's up to you.

```
Node fileHead = null;
Node lineHead = null;
Node currentLine = null;

tokenize file                            // Read the file in line by line
for each line in the file
    Node currentWord = null;             // Keep track of which word was the last added
    tokenize line
    for each word in the line
        if lineHead is null              // Check to see if this is the 1st word
            lineHead = new Node();       // If so, set it to the head node for the line
            lineHead.value = word;
            currentWord = lineHead;      // Make this your current word
        else                             // If this isn't the 1st word of the line
            Node node = new Node();      // Create a new node
            node.value = word;
            currentWord.next = node;     // Set the previous node's "next" to the new one
            currentWord = node;          // Update your current node to this new one
    if fileHead is null                  // If this is the 1st line of the file
        fileHead = lineHead;             // Make the 1st line's 1st word the start
        currentLine = fileHead;          // Update the current line to this 1st one
    else                                 // If this isn't the 1st line of the file
        currentLine.next = lineHead;     // Make the 1st word of this line the start of the next line
        currentLine = currentLine.next;  // Update the current line to this new one
    lineHead = null;                     // Reset the head of the line to null
```

I'm not positive, for I just drafted this up, but something like this should work, or at least point you in the right direction. I personally prefer doubly-linked lists...